# Why modulo equal to & for values of base 2?

Tags: java, algorithm, hashmap, bit-manipulation

It is commonly used in `java.util.HashMap`

```
/**
 * Returns index for hash code h.
 */
static int indexFor(int h, int length) {
    return h & (length-1);
}
```

where length is base 2.

Or Lucene bloom filter code (org.apache.lucene.codecs.bloom.FuzzySet)

```
// Bloom sizes are always base 2 and so can be ANDed for a fast modulo
int pos = positiveHash & bloomSize;
```

It dosn't make sense to me because for example for 8 the difference between `i % 8` and `i & 8` is not zero!

```
    scala> (0 to 20).map(i => (i & 8) - (i % 8))
res33: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -3, -4)
```

Comment: The proper comparison is between `i & 7` and `i % 8`, and `i & 7 == i % 8` for all nonnegative `i`.

Comment: Yeah, they named `bloomSize` poorly, since the array is one bigger, e.g., `FixedBitSet bits = new FixedBitSet(longs,bloomSize+1);`

Comment: Thanks, yes it is traceable in HashMaps although Lucene bloom filter is  logic is still confusing.

Comment: "Why modulo equal to & for values of base 2?" It isn't. Not a real question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither HashMap nor FuzzySet is &'ing on a power of 2 precisely - they are using an integer of the form `2^n - 1`.  The comment you cited from FuzzySet is unfortunately misleading in this regard, but if you do a little digging, you can find this code block:

```
//The sizes of BitSet used are all numbers that, when expressed in binary form,
//are all ones. This is to enable fast downsizing from one bitset to another
//by simply ANDing each set index in one bitset with the size of the target bitset
// - this provides a fast modulo of the number. Values previously accumulated in
// a large bitset and then mapped to a smaller set can be looked up using a single
// AND operation of the query term's hash rather than needing to perform a 2-step
// translation of the query term that mirrors the stored content's reprojections.
static final int usableBitSetSizes[];
static
{
  usableBitSetSizes=new int[30];
  int mask=1;
  int size=mask;
  for (int i = 0; i < usableBitSetSizes.length; i++) {
      size=(size<<1)|mask;
      usableBitSetSizes[i]=size;
  }    
}
```

The bitsize variable in FuzzySet is always ultimately assigned from this array.  The comment here, as well, describes exactly what is going on.

To compute `X % 8 (1000)` is to compute `X & 7 (0111)`.  This holds for all powers of 2.